# Linux Cent OS (6) to allow phpMyAdmin

Tags: linux, phpmyadmin

Linux Cent OS (6) to allow phpMyAdmin
Forbidden
You don’t have permission to access /phpMyAdmin on this server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the permission of your phpMyAdmin directory by command ll.
And then give the directory suitable permission that your web server user can read and write by command chmod.

Comment: This my config phpmyadmin.conf

<Directory /var/www/vhosts/phpMyAdmin/>
        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from  my_ip
</Directory>

Alias /phpMyAdmin /var/www/vhosts/phpMyAdmin/

But again 
You don't have permission to access /phpmyadmin/ on this server.
Please help me